# Using Absolute Referencing with offset VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reference, offset, absolute

I am currently trying to develop that:

First, using a loop populates the numbers 0 to 1500 each like 8 columns apart, and then using another to loop to populate values from another worksheet but I want to use offset and so the numbers 0 to 1500 are the number of rows I want to offset each time. So 0 rows,1 row,2 rows etc.

I am trying to absolutely reference the column from which I will be offsetting the values on the other sheet (which is called DEX Spread Report (Corp)). However, I am having trouble absolutely referencing the column (Column D row 7) as I am not familiar with VBA's method.

Help would be much appreciated! Thanks

```
Sub Output_Numbers_For_Purpose_of_Offsetting_From_DexCorp()

Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("B1").Select

For i = 0 To 1500

    ActiveCell.Value = i
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Select

Next i

Range("B1").Select

For m = 0 To 1500

If ActiveCell.Value = m Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'!   (Range("D7").FormulaR1C1 = "C[0]*10"), m, 0)
Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(8, 0).Select
Next m
End Sub
```

**EDIT - Incorporate Code from comments**

I am getting an issue at:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'! (Range("D7").FormulaR1C1 = "C[0]*10"), m, 0)
```

I am trying to structure it as:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'!$D7,m,0 )
```

Comment: what is that `.FormulaR1C1 = "C[0]*10"` for?

Comment: apparently absolute referencing in vba is done in a some manner of this sort, I am pretty sure what I have done is wrong but am not sure how

Comment: as to me you should update your question explaining in more detail what your code should do and how the data are organized before and after the macro runs

Comment: I am getting an issue at: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'! (Range("D7").FormulaR1C1 = "C[0]*10"), m, 0) 
     
I am trying to structure it as: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'!$D7,m,0

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
 Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("B1:B1000")

    If r.Value = m Then
    'stuff
    Else
    'stuff
    End If

Next r
```

Another way:

```
    Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("B1")

For m = 1 To 1500

    If r(m, 1).Value = m Then
    'stuff
    Else
    'something else
    End If


Next m
```

Comment: I am getting an issue at: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'!   (Range("D7").FormulaR1C1 = "C[0]*10"), m, 0)

Comment: I am trying to structure it as:  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'!$D7,m,0 )

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you correctly, you seem to be trying to get your formula to offset the `$D7` reference as if you had manually pasted it into `B2` and copied it across the worksheet.

I'll offer an alternative solution, since you seem to know that you'll always want to offset by 8 rows. Rather than deal with however VBA wants to absolute cell references, why not just calculate the row number? `(m * 8) + 7` will give you `$D7` at `0`, `$D15` for `1`, and so on.

```
Sub Output_Numbers_For_Purpose_of_Offsetting_From_DexCorp()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim m As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B1").Select

    For i = 0 To 1500
        ActiveCell.Value = i
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Select
    Next i

    Range("B1").Select
    For m = 0 To 1500
        If ActiveCell.Value = m Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=Offset('DEX Spread Report (Corp)'!$D" & (m * 8) + 7 & "," & m & ", 0)"
            Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Select
    Next m
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

quite hard to follow your code

maybe you were for this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Output_Numbers_For_Purpose_of_Offsetting_From_DexCorp()
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 0 To 1500
            .Range("B1").Offset(, i * 8) = i
        Next i

        For i = 0 To 1500
            With .Range("B1").Offset(i * 8)
                If .Value = i Then
                    .Offset(1, 0).Value = Worksheets("DEX Spread Report (Corp)").Range("D7").Offset(i + 6)
                Else
                    .Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
                End If
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```